# Writing append only gzipped log files in Python

Tags: python, gzip

I am building a service where I log plain text format logs from several sources (one file per source). I do not intend to rotate these logs as they must be around forever.

To make these forever around files smaller I hope I could gzip them in fly. As they are log data, the files compress very well.

What is a good approach in Python to write append-only gzipped text files, so that the writing can be later resumed when service goes on and off? I am not that worried about losing few lines, but if gzip container itself breaks down and the file becomes unreadable that's no no.

Also, if it's no go, I can simply write them in as plain text without gzipping if it's not worth of the hassle.

Comment: Even if you don't intend to rotate the logs, why not break the output and start a new file every once in a while? Then you can run gzip after a file is finished.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky's answer is the traditional solution. It's just standard log rotation, except that you leave out the part where you delete the old files.

Answer (score 8):

Note: On unix systems you should seriously consider using an external program, written for this exact task:

- [`logrotate`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) (rotates, compresses, and mails system logs)

You can set the number of *rotations* so high, that the first file would be deleted [in 100 years](https://serverfault.com/a/50185/4346) or so.

---

In Python 2, `logging.FileHandler` takes an keyword argument `encoding` that can be set to `bz2` or `zlib`.

This is because `logging` [uses](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8ee6d96a1019/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l919) the `codecs` module, which in turn treats `bz2` (or `zlib`) as *encoding*:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> with codecs.open("on-the-fly-compressed.txt.bz2", "w", "bz2") as fh:
...     fh.write("Hello World\n")

$ bzcat on-the-fly-compressed.txt.bz2 
Hello World
```

---

Python 3 version (although the docs [mention](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) `bz2` as alias, you'll actually have to use `bz2_codec` - at least w/ 3.2.3):

```
>>> import codecs
>>> with codecs.open("on-the-fly-compressed.txt.bz2", "w", "bz2_codec") as fh:
...     fh.write(b"Hello World\n")

$ bzcat on-the-fly-compressed.txt.bz2 
Hello World
```

Comment: +1 for the link explaining how to use `logrotate` for this purpose. (Well, except that I already gave you +1 for explaining how to do it in Python, if you really want to…)

Comment: Moved logrotate up because I guess it would be the right thing to do.