# Python3 compress logger module logs on the fly

Tags: python, logging, python-3.x, compression

I can't find a way to compress the logs I write with `logger` module.

For example:

```
import logging
import gzip

logger = logging.getLogger('')
z_file = gzip.open('out.log.gz', mode='wb')
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(z_file))
logger.warning("test".encode("UTF-8"))
```

Both `codecs.open` and `gzip.open` give me

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 966, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/gzip.py", line 343, in write
    self.crc = zlib.crc32(data, self.crc) & 0xffffffff
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

When I'm trying to use their handlers. What am I doing wrong?

Related question that doesn't include `logger` module: [Writing append only gzipped log files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14636640/854477)

Comment: Please create the shortest possible complete program that demonstrates the error you see. Copy-paste that short, complete program into your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify `encoding` to `gzip.open`. You should use explicit text mode (`wt`) to specify encoding. And just pass a string to the logging methods.

```
import logging
import gzip

logger = logging.getLogger('')
z_file = gzip.open('out.log.gz', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8')
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(z_file))
logger.warning("test")
```

Comment: Looks like the first version can at least be moved below.

Comment: @int_ua, I usually leave it as is. Otherwise, it could confuse future reader. The current layout(?) matches the question layout.

Comment: I've edited the question. I think it will speed up those who search for an answer.